# iTunes Connect Media Manager - app preview not downsizing

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, app-preview

I uploaded an app preview for the 5.5 inch display in iTunes Connect and then used the new Media Manager to use the same assets for all smaller size classes. Below are images for context:

[image: iTunes Connect Media Manager #1]
[image: iTunes Connect Media Manager #2]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see I'm getting the following error when I try to save/submit my app for review:

> Your app preview can't be uploaded because you have selected to use an app preview from a larger display size

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Contact iTunes Connect support, because it looks like an obvious error on Apple's side.

Answer (score 1):

Check properly the screenshots you have attached. In All you have selected "Use 5.5 inch Display".

Like that:

[image]

Simply do this things:

- Simply uncheck it
- Make sure for 3.5 inch display you have screenshots of 3.5 inch size & so on for others
- Save & submit again for review

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This didn't work. I just ended up unchecking the "User 5.5-inch images" box and just re-added everything manually and canned the new feature and it worked. So much for the slick new feature...

Comment: @Aaron ok so you finally resolved. Did you got any help from my answer ?

Comment: Nothing helped. I'll let those with similar issues decide what answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting every screenshot and uploading them again. And when you're saving the screenshots, don't forget to set the scale of the simulator to 100% (Cmd+1), I only had problem with this.

> Screenshot requirements are:
>
> - 72 dpi, RGB, flattened, no transparency
> - High-quality JPEG or PNG image file format
> - 1242 x 2208 pixels for hi-res portrait
> - 2208 x 1242 pixels for hi-res landscape

*[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2)*

However, if that doesn't solve it, the problem might be with the App Preview, as the error message says. Check the preview's size, it has to match the iPhone 6 Plus resolution.

[App Preview Resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4zi0.png)

Comment: Every asset I used was transferred over from the previous app version submission so all the app previews and images worked correctly and were the right dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue some minutes ago.

I unchecked "Use 5.5-Inch Display" for all smaller devices. Some of them then revealed old app preview assets from previous versions (which were apparently somehow available in background causing this issue). I deleted all of those old smaller-device-assets, saved (i.e. sections for smaller devices were empty). I then re-checked "Use 5.5-Inch Display", saved again. Got no error message afterwards.

Still seems to be a bug on Apple side though. Should also work w/o manually removing old assets before imho. In fact, it even did work at first for me. Error then suddenly occurred when saving a completely different section (description).

Comment: I believe it's a bug on Apple's side unfortunately. I didn't manually remove any assets and then when I toggled "use 5.5-inch display" on and off it removed all the old assets so that part worked like you said but it still threw the error.